# Few questions about utf-8

Tags: utf-8

I have few questions about UTF-8

1. Is it possible to encode any Unicode with UTF-8 ?
2. Does utf-8 allow to encode any ascii character using only 1 byte ?
3. Is length of UTF-8 encoding fixed ?

My answers to check :

1) No, it's not possible. It is possible to encode 1,112,064 out of 1,114,112 codes

2) Yes

3) No, it could be 1,2,3 or 4 bytes

Comment: all questions answered  [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

Comment: I read this, but I am not sure if I understood it correctly ( especially the first question ) . I'd be grateful if somebody could check this ( I updated question with my answers )

Comment: Is there anybody who can help ?

Answer (score 0):

For question (1), what do you mean by "any Unicode"?

Do you mean "Any valid unicode character"? Then yes.

Do you mean "any possible character value from 0x0 to 0x10FFFF, including the 2048 surrogate code points that are not valid unicode character values?" Then no, but only because a valid UTF-8 decoder should reject those values.

The scheme defined by UTF-8 is perfectly capable of encoding those surrogate values in isolation, and in fact it's simpler to write UTF-8 encoding/decoding software that just handles those values like any other.